# About column like another column

Tags: sql, oracle

Column_a like Column_b in same table. When Column_b is `null`, I want it return false.

```
select * from t1 where t1.marvel like '%'||t1.dc||'%'
```

When `t1.dc` is `null`, it become `t1.marvel` like `'%%'`

I don't want `t1.dc` dull to be selected.

Thank You!

Answer (score 2):

Sample data might help; without it, here's how I understood the question.

```
SQL> with t1 (marvel, dc) as
  2    (select 'Littlefoot', 'lefo' from dual union all
  3     select 'Bigfoot'   , null   from dual              --> don't return this one ...
  4    )
  5  select *
  6  from t1
  7  where marvel like '%' || dc ||'%'
  8    and dc is not null;                                 --> ... so add this condition

MARVEL     DC
---------- ----
Littlefoot lefo

SQL>
```